# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzak.class

Tags: java, android, gradle

im working with android,

When the gradle syncs works good, but if I try to compile show me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzak.class
```

Follow the another answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242647/com-android-build-api-transform-transformexception-java-util-zip-zipexception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749583/duplicate-entry-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzqv-class-android-studio)  ,
if I delete google play services, result its same.

But the result its same, my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.procibernetica.moca"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'

    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'


    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'

    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile 'org.msgpack:msgpack:0.6.11'

    compile 'com.theneura:android-sdk:+'

    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile project(':moca-sdk-android-1.9.6')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: any manually libs added ?

Comment: yes, why? id bad make manual?

Comment: mention them also please

Comment: look this  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Yeah, if I add google play services as android studio recommends its works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the tutorial: 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
I remove:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
```

And change for:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
```

And works